# How to generalize model class in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have spring mvc application using mysql database and hibernate framework.II have 4 main classes .A single main class will contain 9 other classes including 3 to 4 one to many relationships.Now  my 4 main classes are identical but are created with different class names and persisted in database .I am not able to re use the code  though all the four main classes have identical attributes. Is there a way I can generalize the model classes such that I can reuse code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity {

    //common attributes, getters/setters, whatever
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "firstTable")
public class ConcreteEntity extends BaseEntity {

    //anything specific to this class, if at all. Can be completely empty
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "secondTable")
public class AnotherConcreteEntity extends BaseEntity {

    //anything specific to this class, if at all. Can be completely empty
}
```